# how to push value to array

Tags: javascript

I have this function

```js
getVal(item){
  var data = [];
  data.push(item);
  console.log(data);
}
```

the value of the variable item is:

```js
4.9000
6.7000
```

I want to insert into an array , but the result in my console is this:

```js
4.9000
6.7000
```

I want the output to be this: `[4.9000, 6.7000 ]`

Do I have to merge first? Or maybe my push technique is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove data from getVal scope. here you make a new array for each execution

```
var data = [];
getVal(item){
  data.push(item);
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to variable data=[] inside the getVal method?

Comment: @gomarkun, technically you can't. It is not the problem about scope, even if you use   global scope, the value for the array will still be cleared every time the function run. Also, I post an answer just now. Check if it works!

Comment: thanks i will try

Answer (score 0):

Your logic with push function is right. But the problem is every time the function run, you clear all the previous value.

An alternative solution is to declare it outside or you could run a for loop:

```js
let data = [];
function getVal(item){
  data.push(item);
}
getVal(1)
getVal(2)
  console.log(data);
```

Run a `for` loop:

```js
let data = [];

 function getVal(item){
  let data = []  
  for(let i in item){
  data.push(i);
  }
  console.log( data)
}

getVal([1,2,3])
```

Comment: thanks i will try

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the initialization of `data` out of the function body. You can avoid the global variable using a closure and an IIFE

```
const getVal = (() => {
  const data = [];
  return (item) => {
    data.push(item);
    console.log(data);
  }
})();
```

Example:

```js
const getVal = (() => {
  const data = [];
  return (item) => {
    data.push(item);
    console.log(data);
  }
})();

getVal(1);
getVal(2);
```